# Proving $M_n := e^{S_n - n/2}$ does not converge in $L^2$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, martingales

Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, where $X_i \sim N(0,1)$ i.i.d. Let $M_n := e^{S_n - n/2}$ and $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_1, \dotsc, X_n)$, then $M_n$ is a martingale w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}_n$.

I need to show that $M_n$ does not converge in $L^2$.
I see that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[M_n^2] &= \mathbb{E}\left[e^{2S_n - n}\right]\\
&= e^{-n}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{2\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}\right]\\
&= e^{-n}\mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^ne^{2X_i}\right]\\
&= e^{-n}\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[e^{2X_i}] \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(Independent)}\\
&= e^{-n}\prod_{i=1}^ne^{2} = e^{-n}e^{2n} = e^n.
\end{align*}
The expectation squared of $M_n$ will grow exponentially as $n \to \infty$ and so I can conclude that $M_n$ does not converge in $L^2$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes a convergent sequence in $L^2$ is bounded in norm, as is true for any NVS! So unbounded means not convergent

Comment: @GeorgeCoote What is NVS?

Comment: Normed vector space, sorry. Put another way, if $M_n$ had a limit $M_\infty \in L^2$, we would have $\mathrm E[M_n^2] \to \mathrm E[M_\infty^2]$. But $\mathrm E[M_n^2] \to \infty$, so $M_\infty$ certainly wouldn't be in $L^2$

Comment: @George Coote Why is that? Convergence in $L^2$ means $E[(X_n^2 - X)^2] \to 0$, right? Oh is it because if $X_n$ converges in $L^2$, then it converges in $L^1$? Then simplify the definition of convergence in $L^2$ to get your alternate definition of convergence in $L^2$?

Comment: It's not a definition, (what you quote is the correct one) indeed $\mathrm E[M_n^2] \to \mathrm E[M_\infty^2]$ is not sufficient for $M_n$ to converge to $M_\infty$ in $L^2$, consider $M_n = (-1)^n$, $M_\infty = 1$. However if $M_n \to M_\infty$ in $L^2$ then $\mathrm E[M_n^2] \to \mathrm E[M_\infty^2]$, this follows from using the reverse triangle inequality for $L^2$. (if you don't know norms yet, I can try to formulate this without them)

Comment: @GeorgeCoote could you please elaborate that last bit? The one where the reverse triangle inequality is used. I know that $| |x| -|y| | \leq | x - y |$.

Comment: I will post as an answer since MSE is nagging about extended discussion as comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSE is nagging me about extended discussions in comments, so I will post as an answer. I'll try to argue this avoiding general ideas about normed vector spaces.

First show that:

$$\sqrt {\mathrm E[(X + Y)^2]} \le \sqrt {\mathrm E[X^2]} + \sqrt {\mathrm E[Y^2]}$$

You'll need to know the Cauchy-Schwartz equality:

$$\mathrm E[|XY|] \le \sqrt{\mathrm E[X^2]} \sqrt {\mathrm E[Y^2]}$$

Then expanding:

$$\begin{align*}\mathrm E[(X + Y)^2] & = \mathrm E[X^2] + 2 \mathrm E[XY] + \mathrm E[Y^2] \\ & \le \mathrm E[X^2] + 2 \mathrm E[|XY|] + \mathrm E[Y^2] \\ & \le \mathrm E[X^2] + 2 \sqrt{\mathrm E[X^2]} \sqrt {\mathrm E[Y^2]} + \mathrm E[Y^2] \\ & = (\sqrt {\mathrm E[X^2]} + \sqrt {\mathrm E[Y^2]})^2\end{align*}$$
Then we get the desired inequality by taking square roots. You can rearrange this to (mimic the proof of the reverse triangle inequality):
$$\left|\sqrt {\mathrm E[X_n^2]} - \sqrt {\mathrm E[X_\infty^2]}\right| \le \sqrt {\mathrm E[{(X_n - X_\infty)^2]}}$$
If we had $X_n \to X_\infty$, we would have $\sqrt {\mathrm E[{(X_n - X_\infty)^2]}} \to 0$, so $\sqrt {\mathrm E[X_n^2]} \to \sqrt {\mathrm E[X_\infty^2]}$. But $\sqrt {\mathrm E[X_n^2]} \to \infty$, so $\sqrt {\mathrm E[X_\infty^2]} = \infty$, so $X_\infty$ can't be in $L^2$, contradiction.

We call $\lVert X\rVert_2 = \sqrt {\mathrm E[X^2]}$ the $L^2$ norm, and it makes $L^2$ into a "normed vector space".

Comment: Right, so in the end you use squeeze theorem to say that $E[X_n^2] \to E[X_{\infty}^2]$. Oh and you of course use the definition of $L^2$-convergence. Hopefully my last question, this is true for any $L^p$-space? Also $p = \infty$?

Comment: In $L^p$ with $p < \infty$ you have the inequality $$\left|(\mathrm E[|X|^p])^{1/p} - (\mathrm E[|Y|^p])^{1/p}\right| \le (\mathrm E[|X - Y|^p)^{1/p}$$. For $p = \infty$ you have $$|\sup |X| - \sup |Y|| \le \sup |X - Y|$$. These are called the "reverse triangle inequality for $L^p$". It fails for $0 < p < 1$.